# Create a radial gradient with a smooth transition

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I want to create something like in the first image, but I am getting something like that in the second image.
After searching for a while, I found out about `radial-gradient` but I am not able to achieve that kind of smooth effect.
I am using Tailwindcss btw .
There is no need for the color to be the same, all I want is to get that smooth transition.

[image: What I want][image: What I got]

My code so far:

tailwind.config.js

```js
            backgroundImage: {
                'gradient-radial': 'radial-gradient(var(--tw-gradient-stops))',
            }
```

```html
<div class="bg-gradient-radial from-purple to-white w-96 h-96 absolute top-24 -left-24 rounded-full"></div>
```

Comment: Please include your code so far, we can't help fix something we can't see. And also perhaps take a look at the MDN documentation for radial gradient: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gradient/radial-gradient

Comment: I have upload my question with the code

Comment: I can't see any edits to the question, are you sure you remembered to save the changes?

Comment: Oops my bad, it is there now

Comment: Ok, next question, what's in the `--tw-gradient-stops` variable?

Comment: `--tw-gradient-stops: var(--tw-gradient-from), var(--tw-gradient-to);` where `--tw-gradient-from` is `#dad2f0` and `--tw-gradient-to` is `#e7e7f2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `bg-gradient-to-l`. "to-l" means to left, you can change it to "to-br" for bottom-right.
`from-blue-100` for first color, `to-red-200` for second color

Here is an example : https://codepen.io/lynnecodes/pen/PoWPZpL

Hope it helps

Comment: But want it to spread in all directions, rather than just on the cardinal directions

Comment: Tailwind gives generic CSS. To achieve a more specific design, we have to use pure CSS. Maybe create your own CSS with the perfect gradient, and apply to your code. Is it a solution for you ?

Comment: Can you show a demo to show something like that in pure css?

Comment: can you inspect the website you show and watch if they did it in css ? If so, you can copy it

Comment: It is actually an image, got it from dribbble

Comment: Ah ok. and these ? https://codepen.io/taylorvowell/pen/AMeqLY

Comment: Um, didn't find anything. But thanks for your help! I ended up creating a gradient using https://cssgradient.io/